# Error with flyway.conf for Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, flyway

Can you please provide an example of **flyway.conf** settings for **Redshift**?
I tried using:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:Redshift://name.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/DBName

flyway.user=user
flyway.password=pass
```

but that produced this error:

```
ERROR: Unable to autodetect JDBC driver for url: jdbc:Redshift:
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues here:

- redshift should be lower case in the jdbc url
- You also need to put the Redshift JDBC driver on the classpath (/drivers directory for Flyway command-line)
- additionally you need to set flyway.driver to the AWS redshift driver class name (Flyway defaults to the standard PG driver: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/redshift.html)